# How do I get an accurate stack base address on OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, pthreads

- [pthread_attr_getstackaddr](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/pthread_attr_set_getstackaddr.3.html) gives me a value like `0xfffffffffff80000` which doesn't seem like a valid base address.
- `pthread_get_stackaddr_np`, such as documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230815/how-do-i-find-the-base-address-and-size-of-the-stack-on-macos-x) and appears to be undocumented and non-portable, gives me a value like `0x00007fff5fc00000` which seems more sensible. However when I place a random breakpoint in my program (with either gdb or lldb) and print the stackpointer I get addresses that are *below* the one returned above (such as `0x00007fff5fbfe7e0`).

All operations are done on `pthread_self` and I never switch threads. Any ideas?

Comment: "I get addresses that are below". On Mac OS X (and on the x86 family processors in general) the stack grows down, from higher to lower addresses. So your variables are supposed to be below the stack base address.

Comment: @n.m.: Oh... I feel stupid now :)

Comment: If you could add that as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X (and on the x86 family processors in general) the stack grows down, from higher to lower addresses. So the variables are supposed to be below the stack base address.